# Return array from soap web service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I use a soap web service.

A Returning of an array from the web service on localhost is ok, **but** on remote host is incorrect

---

***return on localhost :***

```
array (size=3)
  'num_1' => int 0
  'num_2' => int 0
  'num_2' => int 0
```

***return in host :***

```
string(5) "Array"
```

What to do?

Could it be the setting for soap in host?

Comment: Try to return the result as :serialize($result); and unserialize the response

Comment: It(serialize) also does not answer

Comment: print_r return is "Array" || not responding